# Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

when I ran command : `yum -y install mod_wsgi` !!

It shows a message Error:
      `Package: mod_wsgi-3.2-7.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115`

Anybody can help me resolve this problem!! thank you!

my os version : Linux host.dallel.com 2.6.32-042stab113.11 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 17:32:04 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What operating system variant/version is this? Version 3.2 of mod_wsgi is many many years old and should no longer be used. The error is basically saying that Apache package isn't installed, or is not up to date.

Comment: so what should I do!!! ???? I must deploy my django app to cpanel server!!! so I must install mod_wsgi to config in file Httpd.conf !!!

Comment: Ask your cpanel or hosting provider. Only they would have any control over the environment if you have none.

Comment: ok I'll do that !! thank you !

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this problem? I'm having the same problem